# By using github action workflow, how to deploy applications to azure web app particular virtual directory path instead of default 'site/wwwroot' path

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to deploy react application into azure web app virtual directory path. I've created a virual directory under configuration-->pathmappings. My virtual directory path is 'site/react'. When i try to run my github action workflow build pipeline, the deplotment was still happend in default path only instead of virtual directory path. How can i acheive this?

I've tried this deploy script in my yml file

```
- name: Deploy to Azure App Service
  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
  with:
    app-name: reactapp
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE }}
    package: ${{ github.workspace }}/build
    slot-name: production
    virtual-application: 'react'
    enable-virtual-application: true
```

Comment: Anyone, please guide me through this.